# pods are going into error state on adding readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

Tags: linux, kubernetes

pods are going into error state on adding readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

```
[root@conclude1 ~]# oc logs -f biller-28525596-l62hn -n biller
{"level":"ERROR","time":"2024-03-27T10:36:06.261Z","caller":"encryptdecrypt/encryptdecrypt.go:142","message":"Failed to create file /tmp/credentials.json due to error: open /tmp/credentials.json: read-only file system"}
{"level":"FATAL","time":"2024-03-27T10:36:06.261Z","caller":"biller/main.go:64","message":"Error creating credentials file: Failed to create file /tmp/credentials.json due to error: open /tmp/credentials.json: read-only file system"}
```

If any folder (like /tmp) needs to be writable then mount it using emptyDir -> how do i apply this?